# Starting the Thieves Guild questline

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have found the Ratway in Riften. I ventured down three doors and could not find how to join the thieves guild. I went all the way down to the Warrens. This is way past the bar where you find the guy who trains in sneak.

How do I join the Thieves Guild?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to speak to their recruiter in the marketplace during the day, where you'll be given a small series of tasks to complete before the guildies in the sewers start to deal with you.

> To join the Thieves Guild the Dragonborn must enter Riften during the
>   day, and speak to Brynjolf, a red-headed Nord male, who can be found
>   in the Riften Marketplace between 8:00 a.m. - 8:00 p.m. Once the
>   Dragonborn is within proximity, Brynjolf will automatically attempt to
>   strike up a conversation in which the Thieves Guild prerequisite quest
>   A Chance Arrangement can be started. Alternatively, in the evenings
>   past 8:00 p.m., the Dragonborn can encounter Brynjolf at The Bee and
>   Barb inn, at which time he will tell the player to speak with him
>   during the day at his stall in the Riften Marketplace.

From: [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thieves_Guild_%28Skyrim%29)